# Ethereum Bridges , Layer-2 , Sidechain ,Offchain ,Crosschain Interoperability

Tags: layer-2, bridge, interoperability

I'm confused with all these terms Bridges , Layer-2 , Sidechain ,Offchain ,Crosschain Interoperability .Are these the scaling solutions for Ethereum ?

Comment: If you study everything at one moment, you will definitely get confused.
learn one by one.